# Keep x11 GUI app forwarded over ssh alive after lost connection

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, x11, putty

I am forwarding gftp with putty from my Ubuntu server to my laptop.

Is it possible to run the program in a way that will allow it to continue working on the server if my laptop looses connection? Even better would be the ability to reconnect to it when I am reconnected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to run it using x11 forwarding, because even thought the application runs on remote server, it still needs to communicate with our machine where is the X-server running (and your GUI).

You should use `nohup` without X11 forwarding if it is not absolutely necessary to run GUI.

If you really need GUI, you should us VNC for this case, since it runs all the stack on remote side.

Comment: Unfortunatily there are a lot of random files I need to download and its just too slow to do with the CLI. I use LFTP sometimes but it just takes too long to get all the transfers started.